# Potential evapotranspiration constant for trees in the area of London

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, environment

I am trying to find the ET<sub>0</sub> (Potential evapotranspiration) under the climate conditions of London (UK) and Coimbra (Portugal) for each month. From what I understand these data is available in the [FAO's website](http://www.fao.org/) but I was struggling to find it.